# Audio quality reduces when using voice chat in various applications

Tags: sound, microphone

I have a strange problem with my audio setup in that when I use voice chat in video games or other applications, the quality of my audio is reduced (akin to a bit-reducing/crusher effect if you are familiar with electronic music production) and it stays this way until I toggle my sound output to analog or digital. It does not matter which one was active beforehand, changing it always seems to fix it. In some cases, simply opening the sound control window restored the audio quality.

I use a Steinberg UR22 audio interface which my headphones and microphone are connected to. The reason I am asking this here is because I have not encountered this issue when using Windows.